# I want open a dialog box containing message periodically to users of app

Tags: android

We want to send messages to app users either through notifications, dialog box or image opening up on their screen every 24 hours telling them that our app is running on their phone.

We were looking to use Notification builder but it has limitation that it only works for api 11 and above and half of all app installations today are for earlier api versions. We are trying to find out which would be the best way to go with this.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with C#?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "Notification builder" is, but you can certainly use [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) and [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) in any API you want.

So, putting it all together, I would use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to fire off an alarm every 24 hours.  Set up this alarm when your application runs, *and* in a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) which is configured to receive BOOT_COMPLETED.  The BOOT_COMPLETED notification allows you to quietly restart the alarm if the device reboots.

The alarm triggers another BroadcastReceiver which puts the notification up.  If the user selects the notification, then your application is launched.  Mostly, the presence of the notification will be all the reminder your user will need.

My notes say that NotificationManager can pop a View up onto the screen, which could be a dialog.  However, I think a simple icon in the status bar would be best, since you're just reminding the user that the application is present.

Oh, p.s., if your application is a service that's running in the background 24/7, then you should also remember to restart it in the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast.

Comment: I'm aware that those are the steps.  The problem is that the notification process returns the following error when run on the phone:


java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.build


I found references in a google search that refer to the NotificationCompat object used for older systems, but it seems to be happening on the newer Notification object as well. I get the same error whether using one or the other.


Here are two examples:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36502
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36359